# ObjectAnimator stop/ cancel/ restart animation on multiple clicks

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I have assigned to onClick method that starts multiple animations w/ following structure

```
private static void aniChain (params)
    final ObjectAnimator step1 = RotateObj(params);

    final ObjectAnimator step2 = AlphaObj(params);
    final ObjectAnimator step3 = ScaleXObj(params);
    final ObjectAnimator step4 = ScaleYObj(params);

    final ObjectAnimator step5 = ScaleXObj(params);
    final ObjectAnimator step6 = ScaleYObj(params);

    final ObjectAnimator step7 = AlphaObj(params);

   step1.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationStart(animation);
            isAnimate = true;  //another control option
            step2.start();
            step3.start();
            step4.start();
        }
    });

    step2.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            step5.start();
            step6.start();
        }
    });

    step6.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            step7.start();
        }
    });

    step7.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            v.setImageDrawable(null);
            isAnimate = false; // another control option
        }
    });

    if (!step1.isStarted()) {
        step1.start();
    }
```

Basically that chain works fine on 1st click but on 2nd or more click it bugs out. Question is how to stop them?

I have tried another conditions for 2nd click which are

```
    if (!step1.isStarted()) {  //if opener is not started then start it
        step1.start();
    }
    if (step1.isStarted()) {   //and if it was started then cancel every 
        step1-7.cancel();      //animation as they are and proceed to end of last animation
        step7.end();
    }
```

However it still bugs out. Cancellation freezes animation here similar to pausing but without option to resume. It never changes state to initial or any other so I pretty much do not understand point of `cancel()`. Anyway according to my logic on 2nd condition check I freeze all animations regardless of their state and proceed to end of last one to remove image.

Somehow multiple after multiple click these animations tend to echo with each other as if they are separate from each other within method calls.

Also tried

```
   if (!isAnimate) {
        step1.start();
    } else if (isAnimate) {
        step1-7.cancel();
        step7.end();
    }
```

Does not work.

Is there any other way to check isRunning() and stop these animations?

## upd

added this

```
    if (!isAnimate) {
        step1.start();
        Log.i("boolean","sun "+ isAnimate);
    } else {
        isAnimate = false;
        Log.i("boolean","sun "+ isAnimate);
    }

    while (step1.isStarted() && isAnimate) {
        step1-2.cancel();
        step7.end();
    }
```

But in that case animation never starts. Adding while to `if`s makes it skip to last step as soon as boolean changes to true but not when there is 2nd click. Guess I need some kind of listener instead of loop.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are calling aniChain() for starting the animation, each and every object of animation i.e. step 1, step 2 .... is created again and again. Try to make them global or at least they should be instantiated once, so that you will be able to work on the same animations objects. For ending the animation step1.end is the right way to stop the animation of the specified object.

Comment: Is there any kind of listener for Running animation? Like onTick for CountdownTImer? That way using public boolean I can stop them.

Comment: or can I add loop within each to check for isRunning and boolean variable? so while it plays it always check for some value and then if change appears switch occurs

Comment: You thought correctly, using boolean flag will help you. Just a correction that, put isAnimate = true in first line of method aniChain() and put isAnimate = false in onAnimationEnd() of step7.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

Added "fake" obj animator with combined duration of all with 0 start 'n stop of random prop. Other animator steps overwrite that prop well while fake one timer continues till the end.

```
    stepFake.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            if (!isAnimate) {
                step7.end();
            }
        }
    });
```